mPDF error: Unable to find xref table - Maybe a Problem with 'auto_detect_line_endings'
When i incorporate a additional PDF page into my PDF form there will come below error
"mPDF error: Unable to find xref table - Maybe a Problem with 'auto_detect_line_endings'".
Some articles tell to us this is incompatible issue between mPDF and PDF file as well as other one is say is that it is a auto detect line ending issue of PHP.
my mPDf version is 6.
i trying to add a PDF file into pdf form . But an error was occured

Please check PHP Configuration to Ensure that the auto_detect_line_endings setting in your PHP configuration file (php.ini) is correctly set. This setting controls whether PHP will automatically detect and adjust the line-endings of files when reading them. It should generally be set to On. You can check and update this in your php.ini file or directly in your script using
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
I hope using this your issue will be resolved.

Thank you for responding to my question. Initially, I attempted the method multiple times without success. However, after converting the PDF from version 1.7 to 1.4, the issue was finally resolved.

The problem stemmed from the PDF file version, specifically version 1.7. To resolve this, I converted it to version 1.4 using the online PDF editor available at "https://www.pdf2go.com/convert-from-pdf". This successfully resolved the issue.
